# Could Grover's algorithm perform a search in N/2 for a match in a particular subset of a hash function preimage?

Tags: quantum-cryptography

Suppose I first define some function f(x) where x is some unsigned 256-bit integer, and the function's output is a set of distinct strings of any length so that output set would be 2^256 unique strings, i.e. a bijection for the specified domain of x.

Example `f(x) = 0xAA || x || 0xBB` (`||` indicates byte concatenation), but it could also be more complex like `f(x) = 0xAA || g(x) || 0xBB`.

Then, if I plugged that function into some Hash_256 function, like so: `Hash_256(f(x))`, could a quantum computer reveal a matching `f(x)` for some known output of the composite function, and that in 2^128 attempts? By treating the composite function as the "black box" function and do a quantum search on x, would that work?

Context: Bitcoin addresses, trying to answer my own question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115782/post-quantum-preimage-resistance-of-hash160-addresses). It is really a message template search against 160-bit hash that I'm after.

Comment: [Can we speed up the Grover's Algorithm by running parallel processes?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4531/4866) in short, for $k$ machine one get $\sqrt{k}$ speed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but note that these operations must be performed serially as Grover's algorithm is highly non-parallelisable. Even if we build quantum computers which can evaluate the function in one cycle and clock rates comparable to modern computers (both very extreme advances) this will take over $2^{80}$-years. If you wish to take 1/10th the time then you would have to buy 100 times more of this high-end quantum computer.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, so a "quantum computer" then really means a single-threaded QCPU? So 2^128 cycles would be slow in single thread, and doing 2 x 2^127 by building 2 QCPUs would linearly increase the expenses right? And they'd be clocked to rates on the scale of GHz, too? Ok, how about 2^80, is that feasible in single-thread? I calculated about 10 million years... or 10 million QCPUs working for a year, yes? Because there are addresses secured using a 160-bit hash, so that's in the danger zone (2^80) then, right?

Comment: re. "highly non-parallelisable" can't we define a bunch of these inner f(x)es so that they compress a 2^256 input space to like 2^248 output space and use that as input to the hash function, and design a family of 8 of these inner functions so that their outputs doesn't overlap meaning we still search the whole space of the hash function domain, could we then be cracking in parallel?

Comment: Highly non-parallelisable means that using $4^k$ CPUs will take time $2^{128-k}$ for the 256-bit problem and $2^{80-k}$ for the 180-bit problem i.e. dividing the search space means that resources scale inverse quadratically with time. Thus a single threaded QCPU running for 10 million years could be replaced 100 trillion QCPUs working for a year.

Comment: Note also that QCPUs currently operate at the kHz rate.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that scaling rule although your 1/10th vs 100 in the answer reveals it. Are there some good reads on why that is so?

Comment: You might like to start with Scott Fluhrer's paper [Reassessing Grover's algorithm](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/811.pdf).